# What is the maximum range of a bullet flying through the sky?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile, drag, distance

**How far would my bullet fly with the following characteristics?**

- 1.2km/second initial velocity
- 45 degree angle into the sky
- 'Normal' atmospheric conditions
- No wind
- Typical high-powered rifles have 5-10 gram bullets

I've tried various [online calculators](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/traj.html) but they only do vacuum, not normal atmospheric conditions, so the range is 102km.

Comment: Ok, so I'm not a student.  I was just curious about this and we looked at MULTIPLE websites for a calculator or a simple equation.  Knowing wind/friction behavior is out of our league, and we got the answer for this question for a vacuum, which isn't helpful at all. You shouldn't be so presumptuous about people asking questions on here.  I'm from Florida, I hunted with a .243 my whole life, so I was curious.

Comment: You could also comment and suggest edits to be more on topic.  That would have been much more constructive.

Comment: And the only work I can show is how far the bullet would travel in a vacuum which isn't helpful at all.  What if not every one asking questions is a physicist?

Comment: The reason the websites work in vacuum is because it is easy.  Two constants ($g$ and initial velocity) and you are done.  Air resistance is *hard*.  You need to specify the bullet carefully, but the drag coefficient varies with velocity.

Comment: Yeah, and just any sort of guidance about air resistance would be interesting to us. I don't know if the bullet would travel 3, 5, or 20 miles and we were curious.

Comment: The fact that the bullet transitions from supersonic to subsonic makes the air resistance **very** hard to calculate.  It becomes a better candidate for experimentation.

Comment: Thanks and yeah, it does seem like a difficult problem.  I was thinking that someone has to have an idea about how far it will travel, or at least a way to distill this question down to a nice thought-experiment.

Comment: I like this question and think it should be reopened. Perhaps the question could be generalized by removing the reference to a specific type of gun and instead asking about the general problem of determining the range of a projectile when air resistance is present. A simplified air resistance model would probably allow for a useful answer at the factor of 2 level or so of accuracy.